# UIScrollView detect pinch zoom end

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I'm trying to get notified when `UIScrollView` is pinch zoomed out beyond its minimum zoom limit and is about to animate back, but I'm finding it very difficult.  Is there a way I can do this with `delegate` methods alone or do I need to override `UIScrollView's` touch handling?

Answer (score 11):

Use `scrollViewDidZoom:` and check if `scrollView.zoomBouncing == YES`. Then use `zoomScale` to determine which direction the view is bouncing.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.zoomBouncing) {
        if (scrollView.zoomScale == scrollView.maximumZoomScale) {
            NSLog(@"Bouncing back from maximum zoom");
        }
        else
        if (scrollView.zoomScale == scrollView.minimumZoomScale) {
            NSLog(@"Bouncing back from minimum zoom");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIScrollView's `scrollViewDidZoom` delegate method to detect the moment it's about to animate back.  You'll see `scrollView.zoomScale` drop below `scrollView.minimumZoomScale` while the view is being pinched.  Then, as soon as the user releases their fingers, `scrollViewDidZoom` will be called once again with `scrollView.zoomScale == scrollView.minimumZoomScale`, but `scrollView.zooming == NO`.

Capturing this moment is fine and all, but attempting to do anything to preempt the bounce-back-to-minimumZoomScale animation seems to have really odd side effects for me.  :(

Comment: what if I want to capture a zoomScale other than minimumZoomScale, like `if !scrollView.zooming && scrollView.zoomScale < 0.6 {do something} `

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift 4.0:**

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.zoomScale == scrollView.minimumZoomScale
    {
        print("zoomed out")
    }
}
```

This will be called exactly when the user has finished zooming and the zoomScale is at its minimum possible value, i.e. when the scroll view is zoomed out completely.

Comment: How can I detect the user pinching to zoom out, if they don't zoom out all the way?

Comment: @Daniel Springer that zoomScale attribute has all the info you need. It will be decreasing as they zoom out, so check to see if zoomScale has decreased without going all the way out (i.e. all the way to minimumZoomScale). If you still have issues ask the question and link it here, I can share an example of that

Comment: In order to check if it decreased, need I save the previous value to a variable of my own?

Comment: Yes exactly. There is nothing built into the scrollView that does this for you, so you would want to track it with your own variable.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did it with `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = 
     [[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                action:@selector(pinched:)] 
                                                               autorelease];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate=self;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    //your code
}
-(void)pinched:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
    if(gestureRecognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        //pinch ended
        NSLog(@"scale: %f",scrollView.zoomScale);
    }
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
                          (UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```